# Why does Asp.Net Core Identity not provide support for claims and tokens for multiple instances of the same provider (ie. different google logins)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a requirement where my Asp.Net Core 3.0 app (using razor pages) needs to allow users to login with more than one google account (or more than one microsoft account etc).

If you ask why, I'd say I am looking to write an aggregator app for any user who wants to see their combined contacts from multiple accounts, so if you have two google accounts, one for your personal and one for your work, and you want a unified view, the ability to link a single Asp.Net Identity account to multiple external logins from the same provider, is a legit requirement.

So, I'd like to store the multiple google user logins (with same provider name but different provider keys) in to the userlogin table, for which there already is support.  But when it comes to saving the tokens and claims for these accounts separately, the out of the box table design correlates them to the user and provider (not the provider key).  So, you can only have tokens for a given user/single provider combo and claims for the single user.  Since the claims and tokens originally come from a specific external login instance (provider/ provider key combo), the table design IMO should be extended to foreign key them to the User Login table, which has both the provider and provider key, instead of the current design of the User table.

Has this been contemplated at all and is there a best practice recommendation to facilitate my goal?